# How to read a data table into R as a matrix

Tags: r

This code is directly from a Bioconductor vignette for creating an expressionSet (http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/2.12/bioc/vignettes/Biobase/inst/doc/ExpressionSetIntroduction.pdf).

```
>  exprs <- as.matrix(read.table(exprsFile, header=TRUE, sep = "\t",
                 + row.names = 1,
                 + as.is=TRUE))
```

Can anyone tell why this code generates the following error message?

```
> exprs <- as.matrix(read.table(exprsFile, header=TRUE, sep = "\t",
+                       row.names = 1,
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"exprs <- as.matrix(read.table(exprsFile, header=TRUE, sep = "\t",
                 + row.names ="
>                      + as.is=TRUE))
Error: unexpected ')' in "                     + as.is=TRUE)"
```

Or, could you suggest an alternative method to read in the file exprsFile as a matrix with header?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Hi. It looks like you copy+pasted the code.   Remove those `+` signs.  When reading a document of `R` code, `+` signs **generally** indicate a continued line when typing into the console.  (a notable exception is in `ggplot` related code, but that is not relevant here)

Comment: Removing + signs solved the problem, thanks!

Comment: The corrected script generated "incomplete final line error". Another post on this site suggested to scroll to the last line of the text file and press enter. Saving the file with that modification fixed the incomplete final line error.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The biobase vignette is (almost certainly) produced using [`Sweave`](http://www.stat.uni-muenchen.de/~leisch/Sweave/). The `>` and leading `+` where single expressions have been split over multiple lines are an artefact of using `Sweave` and how it displays code it processes. It reflects how the terminal / console (R session) would looked if you had entered the following (which should work)

```
exprs <- as.matrix(read.table(exprsFile, header=TRUE, sep = "\t",
                  row.names = 1,
                  as.is=TRUE))
```

[`knitr`](http://yihui.name/knitr/) (which is an alternative to `Sweave`, and is now permitted for vignettes, by default has these `prompts` removed, so code is more directly copy-and-pastable.